# Change the class of wordpress menu

Tags: plugin-development, menus

I have problems with wordpress menu level classes.

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>
```

this is the code i used to generate my menu,

First level menu id is

> ul id="menu-home"

second level class is

> ul class="sub-menu"

but my third level menu also has same class as second level

> ul class="sub-menu"

is there any way to change the class of third level or some other solution???

please help..
thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will add class `sub-menu-0`, `sub-menu-1` and so on depending upon their depth.

```
//This will go in functions.php file
class wpse61220_submenu_class extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
  function start_lvl(&$output, $depth) {
    $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
    $output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"sub-menu-".$depth."\">\n";
  }
}

//  Usage -
//  wp_nav_menu( array('walker' => new wpse61220_submenu_class() ) );
```

*<sup>**Reference** - function [`wp_nav_menu()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu)</sup>*